# The information property list required device capabilities

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to understand the difference between this list: `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` and individual keys such as: `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi`. Is the list for AppStore to filter which devices is allowed to download the application but the individual keys are for "configuring" purposes in my app?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12

Comment: You are right. As stated in the documentation UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities filters devices. Other keys configure the OS behaviour while executing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly right.  Wifi, for example, is a setting, and can be turned on and off by the user but the capability exists on all devices, so obviously it cannot be used to filter devices, right?  :).  The others are not requirements, but settings for application behavior.

To summarize:
The things in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities either exist or they don't (for example, armv7 architecture) on any given device.  If you add one to the list, devices without it will not be allowed to install.

The others are settings that define how your application works and looks (status bar style, antialiasing, etc etc), but it will install on any device capable of running iOS.